# Connecting to MS SQL Server from MAC application with FreeTDS fails

Tags: sql-server, macos, t-sql, freetds, iodbc

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server from my Mac application using iODBC and FreeTDS. No matter what I do, I get the error message Unable to connect to data source from the FreeTDS driver. i have consulted as many possible  manuals, blog posts, and StackOverflow questions.

Following is the troubleshooting steps i tried and more details about my code,

```
DB Connection string = Driver=/Applications/xxx.app/Contents/Frameworks/libtdsodbc.so;Server=ip;DATABASE=DB;TDS_Version=8.0;Port=1433;ClientCharset=UTF-8;uid=username;pwd=*****;Trusted_Connection=No;
```

From application logs,

```
SQLGetDiagRec function returns
[01000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed (20002)
[08001] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0)
```

Few StackOverflow post's suggested this is due to TDS version and changing to 8.0  would help but its already set.

When I ping the server - no packets are lost.
Connection is established when i telnet the server on 1433 port.

Using the below i am able to establish connection too,

```
tsql -H >IP< -p 1433 -U username -P password
```

In this  [particular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066716/freetds-not-using-its-config) as per the comments by  [Max Bolingbroke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16219721/5307724)
if SERVER attribute is used then freetds.config and odbc.ini are ignored. So i guess the config file parameters dont help much.

Could anyone please provide me with some pointers or any help so i can proceed further.

Comment: A few things. Consider using unixODBC; this answer gives some good reasons why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548825/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-iodbc-and-unixodbc `TDS_Version` 8.0 doesn't exist; try 7.2 if you're on SQL Server 2008: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Comment: One thing i missed out in my post is that the connection works for most of the environment setups except a few with similar configurations. Is there any way to find why those few are not able to connect ?            @FlipperPA i will try out your suggestion to changing the version to 7.2 but  using unixODBC at this point would not be possible as the application is already in production environment.