# Is there an ODBC connector for .NET Core that use iODBC when targeting linux instead of unixODBC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, odbc, unixodbc, iodbc

I'm currently building a API in ASP.NET that is supposed to extract large amount of data from HyperFileSQL (PCSOFT). While there is a linux ODBC Driver provided by PCSOFT for their DB system, it's build around iODBC and thus not compatible with System.Data.Odbc.

Do someone knows of an ODBC connector that can be configured or compiled to use iODBC instead of unixODBC when targeting linux ? Or of a way to use a driver built for iODBC with unixODBC ?

I tried using System.Data.Odbc but the driver is not found because it's looking for driver in unixODBC. Accessing the database with iodbctest in cmd is however functional.

Answer (score 0):

[Recent versions of iODBC](https://github.com/openlink/iODBC/releases) *should* work with both drivers and applications built with the UnixODBC SDK as well as with the iODBC SDK.

It's not clear what you mean by "the driver is not found because it's looking for driver in unixODBC". My best guess is that you have multiple `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files, and possibly both iODBC and UnixODBC driver managers installed, in different locations.

Unifying these -- i.e., blending the content of all `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini`, respectively, and putting physical files at one location (e.g., `/usr/local/`) and symlinks at all other current locations -- and picking one set of driver manager libraries, and either deleting the others or making sure that the libraries you've chosen always come first when drilling through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ... *may* be all you need to do, to achieve your goal.

Comment: It seems to me that I'm missing something, I did blend the content and symlink everything to the same base odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini but I still can connect using my C# code or trough isql.
Does not work with isql :
`isql -v TestHfsql Admin
[IM005][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_DBC failed
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect`

But does work with iodbctest :
`iodbctest DSN=TestHfsql
iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0812.0326
Driver: 28.00.22700 (wd280hfo64.so)

SQL>`

Comment: iODBC 03.52.0812.0326 is more humanly understandable as 3.52.08 as of 2012-03-26. Version 3.52.16 is current, and strongly recommended, as it brings much improvement to cross-manager compatibility. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66247796/241164 for many details!